# C++ Weird behavior with String comparison

Tags: c++, string

I am using [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh) to compile and run this code. I am expecting the value of `number` to be either default initialized to `0` or some garbage value. However, in the constructor, even though the `if` condition is false, the value of `number` is still initialized to `10`. Can someone explain to me what's happening?

```
#include <iostream>

class Number
{
    int number;
public:
    Number(std::string s)
    {
        if (s == "foo")
        {
            number = 10;
        }
    }
    int getNumber()
    {
        return number;
    }
};

int main()
{
  Number n("bar");
  std::cout << n.getNumber() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Reading from uninitialized variable is *undefined behaviour*. Anything could happen, including this.

Comment: non-`class` variables (with non-`static` storage) are default initialized to *indeterminate* values, not to 0

Comment: Add `number = 0;` before `if (s == "foo")`

Comment: I wonder whether that's the compiler being clever and avoiding the `if` because it's able to determine that if the branch isn't taken, using `number` would be UB anyway and that an integer assignment being quite cheap, it might as well always assign it or that's only a coincidence. You made me curious.

Comment: @Caninonos, yes, that is, I did some test and it is a specific compiler optimization. See my answer below.

Comment: "_I am expecting the value of `number` to be either default initialized to `0` or some garbage value._" `10` is just as valid "garbage value".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From clause 9 in [[dcl.decl]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/open/n2356/decl.html)

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized. When storage for an object
>   with automatic or dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object has an *indeterminate value*, and if
>   no initialization is performed for the object, that object retains an indeterminate value until that value is
>   replaced

Value 10 is placed just as optimization done by compiler to eliminate conditional statement.

Answer (score 5):

It's a compiler optimization on the constructor. You can check it changing the optimization level.

As the data member `number` is not initialized, the value of the variable is following the UB rule. That said the compiler (cpp.sh cited above) optimize the constructor at Full (-O2) assigning always 10, as it's times cheaper than trying to do the string comparison and make a jump or an assignment.

Tried to change the optimization level to `normal` and it didn't happen.

Tried with VS 2017, debug & release and it doesn't happen.

It's an optimization done by the compiler. Specifically by the compiler used by cpp.sh at `Full (-o2)`

Answer (score 3):

So, in this lucky case undefined behavior causes that number is treated as initialized by 10 (but actually it is not!). Trying to use this will cause more UB in your code.

To avoid such problems, prefer to always initialize a variable with some value. For example:

```
Number(std::string s)
    : number ( -1 )
{
    if (s == "foo")
    {
        number = 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

All the primitive data types should be initialized. Here you are accessing an `int` without initializing. You can initialize the variable while declaring using `{}`. For example, see below code  -

```
class Number
{
    int number {0}; // or any other default value.
};
```

Please note that accessing uninitialized variable is **Undefined Behavior**. For more details regarding Undefined Behavior, you can see this - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Answer (score 2):

In case s is not `"foo"` your code leaves number **uninitialized** when constructing an instance of `Number`. Then when you read the value of number using `n.getNumber()` you invoke **undefined bahavior**. This means the value of returned by this function can be any integer number (including by chance the value 10 that you don't expect).

Comment: I think it is initialized to 10 not by chance, but by compiler

Comment: @Yola I don't think it is deterministic, definitely in similar situations I've seen different values returned in different executions

Comment: I believe compiler just wanted to eliminate conditional statement.

Comment: @Yola or it is accessing some memory without changing its value and it happened to be 10 (for instance from a previous run of the program)